# How to resolve "Invalid Sequence Token" when using cloudwatch agent?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm seeing the following warning in the  `/var/log/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log`:

```
2021-10-06T06:39:23Z W! [outputs.cloudwatchlogs] Invalid SequenceToken used, will use new token and retry: The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: 49619410836690261519535138406911035003981074860446093650
```

But there is no mention about which file is really the one that it's failing. Not even when I add  `"debug": true` to the `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json`.

```
cat /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json|jq .agent
{
  "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
  "debug": true,
  "run_as_user": "root"
}
```

I have many (28) files in my `.logs.logs_collected.files.collect_list` section of the `config.json` file, so how can I find which file is exactly causing trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2021-11-29 a PR to improve the log messages has been [merged](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/pull/290) to the cloudwatch-agent but a new version of the cloudwatch-agent has not been released yet, the next version after v1.247349.0 will likely include a fix for this.

The fix will change the log statements to say

- `INFO: First time sending logs to %v/%v since startup so sequenceToken is nil, learned new token: xxxx: yyyy`: This is an INFO message, as this behaviour is expected at startup for example.
- `WARN: Invalid SequenceToken used (%v) while sending logs to %v/%v, will use new token and retry: xxxxxv`: This on the other hand is not expected and may mean that someone else is writing to the loggroup/logstream concurrently.

---

If those warnings come right after a restart of the cloudwatch agent (cwagent) then you can safely ignore them, it's **expected behaviour** . The cloudwatch agent does not save the next sequence token in its persistent state so on restart it will "learn" the correct sequence number by issuing a PutLogEvent with no sequence token at all, that returns an [InvalidSequenceTokenException](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cloudwatchlogs/#InvalidSequenceTokenException) with the next sequence token to use. So it's **expected** to see those at startup, anyway I proposed a [PR to amazon-cloudwatch-agent to improve those log messages](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/pull/290).

If the "Invalid SequenceToken used" is seen long after the restart then you may have other issues.

The "Invalid SequenceToken used" error usually means that two entities/sources are trying to write to the same log group/log stream as mentioned in [2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/push-log-data-cloudwatch-awslogs/) (which is really for the old awslogs agent but still useful):

> Caught exception: An error occurred (InvalidSequenceTokenException)
> when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The given sequenceToken is
> invalid[…] -or- Multiple agents might be sending log events to log
> stream[…] – You can't push logs from multiple log files to a single
> log stream. Update your configuration to push each log to a log
> stream-log group combination.

I could be that the amazon cloudwatch agent itself it's trying to upload the same file twice because you have duplicates in your `config.json`.

So first print all your log group / log stream pairs in your `config.json` with:

```
cat /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json|jq -r '.logs.logs_collected.files.collect_list[]|"\(.log_group_name) \(.log_stream_name)"'|sort
```

which should give an output similar to:

```
/tableauserver/apigateway apigateway_node5-0.log
/tableauserver/apigateway control_apigateway_node5-0.log
/tableauserver/appzookeeper appzookeeper-discovery_node5-1.log
...
/tableauserver/vizqlserver vizqlserver_node5-3.log
```

Then you can use `uniq -d` to find the duplicates in that list with:

```
cat /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json|jq -r '.logs.logs_collected.files.collect_list[]|"\(.log_group_name) \(.log_stream_name)"'|sort|uniq -d
# The list should be empty otherwise you have duplicates
```

If that command produces any output it **means that you have duplicates in your config.json collect_list**.

I personally think that cwagent itself should print the "offending" loggroup/logstream in the logs so I opened  in [issue in amazon-cloudwatch-agent GitHub page](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/issues/287).

Comment: Thanks Ruben. In my case was a log from beanstalk to cloudwatch. It was just a warning because log is correctly uploaded.